# How to eliminate line break in that very specific context?

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I try alomst every `display:`,`<span>`,`white-space`,`overflow:auto`, etc, and search a lot on this site. How to eliminate does damns line breaks on that really specific case. Could you show me, even if its simple ? :)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.width = screen.width + "px";
  document.getElementById("container").style.height = screen.height + "px";

}
```

```css
#container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: indianred;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

[LINE BREAK IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDIx5.png)

Comment: That's called "margin" you can get rid of it with `html, body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

`body { margin: 0; }`

in your css should do the trick. The browser is adding some default styles to the body by the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
```

or

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use normalize.css to  cross-browser consistency in the default styling of HTML elements,
You can download it from here : https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
or you can add via CDN :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
```